# Rounded corners for lesser z-index elements

Tags: html, z-index, css

I'm trying to design a website in which the main content container has rounded corners using the border-radius property. However, I am keeping a sidebar and a topside navbar fixed so they don't move when a user scrolls up or down. It's similar to what can be seen on Google Plus:

http://www.techzek.com/wp-content/uploads/gsmarena_00121.jpg.

My question is: How do I set a border-radius for a content-container with a z-index value less than the other elements so that the rounded corners are not overlapped and hidden by other elements when a user scrolls?

In the following example, I'd like the corner where the navbar and sidebar meet to be curved, but can't figure out how

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar"></div>

    <div class="contentcontainer"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```css
html, body {
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    display:inline;
    z-index:2;
    background: rgb(61,40,77);
}

.navbar ul{
    float:right;
    display:block;
    padding-top:14px;
    padding-right:10px;
}

.navbar li {
    padding:15px;
    display:inline;
}

.sidebar {
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    margin-top:50px;
    width:170px;
    background: rgb(61,40,77);
    color: #eee;
}

.contentcontainer {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:200px;
    margin-top:65px;
    z-index:1;
    width:82%;
    max-width:980px;
    background-color:#fbfbfb;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:black;
    border-radius:18px;
}
```

Comment: show what you have/tried. We can't help you without seeing any code. However, if you're just having problems where the content of a container is overlapping the container's rounded corner, either make the content also rounded corners, or add padding.

Comment: For me, at least, it's hard hard to see exactly what you're referring to in the image. Do you have something in a higher resolution, or maybe a link to a demo page you're working on?

Comment: This is more of a general question. The actual code is way too long to post here. Let's say I have a fixed navbar and sidebar like on Google Plus with z-index 4. I have a content-container with z-index 2. If I use the border-radius property on the content-container and the user scrolls down, will the navbar scroll over and overlap the rounded corners of the content-container?

Comment: you can make a test case on jsfiddle and post here. but like I said, for something like that I would just add padding so it doesn't overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? [Codepen](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/sBzIb)
Here's the trick. You make a circle with `border-radius`. You place it in the intersection berween the nav and the sidebar. Set `border-color: transparent` and get some shadow to set the color.

```
.sidebar:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 0px;
  right: -20px; /* negative (border-width * 2) */
  border-radius: 10px; /* same as border-width */
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: -10px -10px 0 rgb(61,40,77); /* first two values = negative border-width */
}
```